# Installing pThreads in Windows

Tags: php, pthreads

Can anyone guide me in installing pThreads in Windows .

Actually i want to enable Threads in PHP .

```
require_once( 'Thread.php' );

// test to see if threading is available
if( ! Thread::available() ) {
die( 'Threads not supported' );
}

// function to be ran on separate threads
function paralel( $_limit, $_name ) {
for ( $index = 0; $index < $_limit; $index++ ) {
    echo 'Now running thread ' . $_name . PHP_EOL;
    sleep( 1 );
}
}

// create 2 thread objects
$t1 = new Thread( 'paralel' );
$t2 = new Thread( 'paralel' );

 // start them
$t1->start( 10, 't1' );
$t2->start( 10, 't2' );

// keep the program running until the threads finish
while( $t1->isAlive() && $t2->isAlive() ) {

}
```

Error displaying is "Threads not supported."

My PHP version 5.3.4 .

Comment: Hi user2454964, have you looked at this: http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Answer (score 5):

- Install ZTS (thread safe) PHP (obligation)
    http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.6-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
- Download Pthread and install
     http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/
   Move php_pthreads.dll to the php\ext\ directory.
   Move pthreadVC2.dll to the php\ directory.
   enter extension=php_pthreads.dll to php.ini
- try examples
    https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/master/examples

Comment: Probably it's neccessary to add `LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/pthreadVC2.dll"` to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is not compatible with pthreads.

Windows binaries for pthreads are available http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/

Simply download the release, unpack the extension dll (php_pthreads.dll) to your extension directory and the runtime dll (pthreadVC2.dll) to your php directory (same dir as php.exe) and add extension=php_pthreads.dll to your configuration

Example pthreads code can be found on github http://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the help. can you please provide me with Threads example in PHP on Windows platform. how to install and run ?